# Run W3 Total Cache Function with Crontab

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, command-line, cron

Ok.  I'm really stumped on this one.

Basically, I need to call a function for the Wordpress plugin W3 Total Cache as part of a cron job in crontab.  I'd like to automatically clear the entire page cache nightly.

Here's the code that works fine within wordpress that I need to call:

```
if (function_exists('w3tc_pgcache_flush')) {
w3tc_pgcache_flush();
}
```

I'm currently using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

define('DOING_AJAX', true);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
$_SERVER = array(
    "HTTP_HOST" => "http://example.com",
    "SERVER_NAME" => "http://example.com",
    "REQUEST_URI" => "/",
    "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
);
require_once('/path-to-file/wp-load.php');

wp_mail('email@example.com', 'Automatic email', 'Hello, this is an automatically scheduled email from WordPress.');

if (function_exists('w3tc_pgcache_flush')) {
w3tc_pgcache_flush();
} 

?>
```

and the command line:

```
php -q /path-to-file/flushtest.php
```

I used the wp_mail function to test and make sure I'm getting something.

The script is working fine except that the page cache is never flushed.  I get the email and there aren't any errors in the log either.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: crontab entries are notorious for the minimal path they use by default. Unless you're setting a PATH to your PHP code in the crontab or a called script, I don't think it will be able to find your php libs. To test this idea, put an else condition to print a warning that w3tc_pgcache_flush does not exist? Good luck.

Comment: Hmm... That might be it.  I'm certainly using a full path to the wp-load.php file.  But it does seem like it can't find what it needs to run the w3tc function.  I figured that the wp-load.php would include everything necessary for that function to get to the wordpress plugin files.  Any ideas on what other file I may need to require?

Answer (score 4):

The better version is now to use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/). The latest version (0.9.2.8) is compatible with this plugin. Just run this command from anywhere in your wordpress directory :

```
wp w3-total-cache flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order a bit an try if it still works:

```
w3tc_pgcache_flush(); # let it crash here so that you won't get the mail
wp_mail('email@example.com', 'Automatic email', 'Hello, this is an automatically scheduled email from WordPress.');
```

Comment: Well, still not working.  But I did get the email both times even if I switched the order.  Perhaps I need something else for that plugin function to be called?

Comment: But your installation under remote debugging, fire up the WP_CRON request and step through to see what happens. Also check if the plugin is able to speak about errors and unmatched preconditions through some  reporting or return values.